# Symfony: Multiple money fields in one form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, currency

Imagine you have an item entity. Within this item entity, there is a method to get the prices for that item. Prices are saved in 3 different formats: EUR, USD and GBP.

The entities would look like this:

Entity WebshopItem.php

```
class WebshopItem
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    ......

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $prices;
}
```

Entity WebshopItemPrice.php

```
class WebshopItemPrice
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var \WebshopItem
     */
    private $webshopItem;
}
```

Now I would like to create a form, which contains exactly 3 input fields. For that, I thought it would be best to use the money field. So I am creating the form like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder
         ->add('title')
         ....
         ->add('prices', new WebshopPricesType());
}
```

The webshopPricesType looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder
         ->add('eur', 'money', array('currency' => 'EUR', 'data_class' => 'bundlePath\Entity\WebshopItemPrice'))
         ->add('usd', 'money', array('currency' => 'USD', 'data_class' => 'bundlePath\Entity\WebshopItemPrice'))
          ->add('gbp', 'money', array('currency' => 'GBP', 'data_class' => 'bundlePath\Entity\WebshopItemPrice'));
}
```

3 correct fields are rendered now. I only need to fill them on edit and when saving, I have to make sure they are saved. I was thinking about using a data transformer to find the correct entity, but that's not working.

How can I make sure that all 3 fields are prefilled correctly on edit and when clicking save, the 3 prices are saved?

Or should I do it on a whole different way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never been too fond of `DataTransformers` and therefore I would not use them here, but they can be useful.

In this particular case, I would go for `FormEvents` and build the form dynamically, based on the data your entity contains.

**<kbd>WebShopItemType</kbd>**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder
         ->add('title')
         .....
         ->add('prices', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new WebshopPricesType()
         ));
}
```

**<kbd>WebshopPricesType</kbd>**

```
class WebshopPricesType extends AbstractType{
    .....

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        // Dynamically build form fields, **after** the data has been set
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($builder){
            /** @var $data WebshopItemPrice **/
            $data = $event->getData(); 

            $builder->add('price', 'money', array('currency' => $data->getCurrency()));
        });
    }

    public function setDefaults(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefault(array(
            'data_class' => 'bundlePath\Entity\WebshopItemPrice'
        ));
    }

    .....
}
```

### **Given that, let's glue it altogether:**

```
public class SomeController extends Controller{
    public function insertAction(){
        $item = new WebshopItem();

        // be sure to initialize the $prices with new `ArrayCollection` 
        // in order to avoid NullPointerException
        // Also, be sure to bind WebshopItemPrice::$item
        $item
            ->addPrice(new WebshopItemPrice('EUR', 0))
            ->addPrice(new WebshopItemPrice('USD', 0))
            ->addPrice(new WebshopItemPrice('GBP', 0));

        // this is where POST_SET_DATA gets fired
        $form = $this->createForm(new WebShopItemType(), $item);

        // form is ready
    }

    public function editAction(){
        $item = ... // fetch or whatever, be sure to fetch prices as well

        // this is where POST_SET_DATA gets fired
        $form = $this->createForm(new WebShopItemType(), $item);

        // form is ready
    }
}
```

I have put this together in Notepad++ and I not sure if I did some typos but as far as logic is concerned - it should work ;)

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll try and let you know later on if it works and if so, mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: Your solution seems to be close, but not completely. I am digging in myself now too: The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Entity\WebshopItemPrice. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Entity\WebshopItemPrice" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Entity\WebshopItemPrice to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.